# Ant: javascript and inheritance

Tags: javascript, java, inheritance, ant

I'm trying to implement a version of [ProfileLogger](https://github.com/apache/ant/blob/master/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/listener/ProfileLogger.java) in JavaScript in an old version of Ant (1.7.1), but I'm stuck on the way to do inheritance since I'm not allowed to redefine methods. Have you got any hints on how to do that?

Edit:
I have tried the follow snippet:

```
<script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
    importClass(Packages.org.apache.tools.ant.DefaultLogger);
    var l = new DefaultLogger();

    var list = {};
    l.targetStarted = function(e) {
        list[e.getName()] = 0;
    };

    l.targetFinished = function(e) {
        println(list[e.getName()]);
    };

    project.addBuildListener(l);
]]></script>
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
x.xml(78) : error: javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: Jav
a method "targetStarted" cannot be assigned to. (<Unknown source>#6) in <Unknown source> at line number 6
Caused by javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: Java method "targetStarted" cannot be assigned to. (<Unknown source>#6) in
 <Unknown source> at line number 6:
        at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:224)
        at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:240)
        at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.invoke(ReflectUtil.java:90)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectWrapper.invoke(ReflectWrapper.java:81)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.evaluateScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:105)
        ...

        at model file x.xml:78

x.model: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s).
Total: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s).
```

Comment: The project you refer to is Java - are you trying to convert to JavaScript?

Comment: it's a mix of a bunch of languages, my goal is just to a JavaScript logger in ant in build.xml.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what code you have so far.

Comment: I hope that it will be clearer

Comment: Never tried that with JavaScript, but maybe a solution with Groovy will be helpful ? http://octodecillion.com/blog/buildlistener-groovy-scriptdef/

Comment: I tried it but it's adding a dependency and it's quite difficult in my project.